# SDL link error, cannot open file 'SDL_lib.obj' in vs2005

Tags: c, sdl, fatal-error

When I compile a project with sdl in Microsoft VS2005, I encounter the problem:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SDL_lib.obj'

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Perhaps you should try to link with `SDL.lib` and not `SDL_lib`?

Answer (score 0):

The distributed SDL lib files are called `SDL.lib` and `SDLmain.lib`. There is no file called `SDL_lib.obj`